# Regex is only capturing the last item in group

Tags: php, regex

I thought I knew regular expressions but I can't work this out.

Trying to get 56 out of this.

```
$s = '<a href="../paye/56.html">';
```

With the following Regex ( PHP - [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)  )

```
preg_match('/href="(.*(\d+)\.html)"/',$s,$m);
```

But it only gives me the 6

```
[
 0 => 'href="../paye/56.html"',
 1 => '../paye/56.html',
 2 => '6' // Need this to be 56
]
```

Regex 101 is trying to help with

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put
>   a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations
>   or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the
>   data

But all my attempts at putting a capturing group around that capture haven't made a difference.

Comment: Sorry typo, regex I was trying was preg_match('/href="(.*(\d+)\.html)"/',$s,$m);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `(\d)+` will match a single digit and put it in capture group, the `+` quantifier will match any digit, but will not capture it. To capture all the digits move the `+` quantifier inside the capturing group.
2. Make the first part `.*` non-greedy by using `?` at the end.

You don't need the parenthesis around the complete string. To capture only the last part in the URL.

```
href=.*?(\d+)\.html
       ^   ^
```

And access the first captured group.

**Code:**

```
$re = "/href=.*?(\\d)+\\.html/"; 
$str = "\$s = '<a href=\"../paye/56.html\">';"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks this is the bit I was missing "Make the first part .* non-greedy by using ? at the end."